# WordNet Java Interface

Tags: java, interface, wordnet

I need to use WordNet with Java. Can anyone point me to some useful resources?

Comment: Have you tried the list of Java resources on the WordNet site? http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#Java.

Comment: No, I hadn't tried the wordnet site. Thank you.

Comment: `No, I hadn't tried the wordnet site` --- faceplant in palm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented a project with WordNet a while back, and I seem to recall using the [JWNL](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jwordnet/index.php?title=Main_Page) API.  The API and [docs](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jwordnet/index.php?title=Developer's_Cookbook) were fairly straight forward (and easy) to use.

Comment: I'm gonna go with RitaWN, by Daniel Howe [email], provides simple access to the WordNet ontology, wraps Jawbone/JWNL functionality for Java/Processing.
thx....

Comment: You can also try out extJWNL http://www.extjwnl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Quick googling shows [some stuff](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/) by gyus from MIT, a [library on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordnet/) and [something, named JAWS](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html).

I haven't used any single one of those libraries, though.

Comment: yeh, since ti was my first time as well. I just wanted to be sure. Thx though

Comment: I used this api before and I was good enought :)