# Require help on accessing WordNet hierarchy for implementing algorithm

Tags: nlp, similarity, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

I am trying to implement Resnik's similarity measure using WordNet hierarchy in java.

Example:- deposit money in bank.
In above example suppose I want to disambiguate DEPOSIT & BANK. So, I will have to 1st access nodes of senses of respective words & then apply algorithm.

**My question is:-
How do I programatically access the WordNet hierarchy/node positions?**

Comment: See related question/answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976537/wordnet-similarity-in-java-jaws-jwnl-or-java-wnsimilarity

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827671/wordnet-java-interface?rq=1

Comment: I understand you already know about JAWS. What's the problem then?

Comment: @Qnan, The reason is:-Say bank1=financial institution;bank2=slope of land near water body, etc. also deposit1=xxx, and deposit2=yyy(gloss). According to Resnik I have to first get the location of the nodes in order to compute the LCS and then only I can apply the algorithm. So LCS for bank1&deposit1 will be different compared to bank1&deposit2.. are you getting me?

Comment: You can use the Java WN Similarity project : http://www.sussex.ac.uk/Users/drh21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the Java WN Similarity project as suggested by @damned

Answer (score 1):

dirty, not efficient, but obvious?: why don't you calculate all the possible pairs of glosses/senses for the given terms and keep the max similarity score (or before that the corresponding LCS min/max, do not know the details of the algorithm) given that the words are in the same context, e.g. phrase, sentence or paragraph level?